# Не работает плагин для множественной загрузки plupload

Tags: php, javascript, плагин

Здравствуйте! Для множественной загрузки файлов я пытаюсь использовать плагин [plupload][1]

[1]: http://plupload.com/ Но почему-то не могу заставить его работать, т.е. форма загрузки отображается, прогресс-бар тоже, пишет, что 100% загружено, а в папке на сервере ничего не появляется, так даже в стандартном примере.
Код скрипта - обработчика на стороне сервера:
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

```
// Settings
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
//$targetDir = 'uploads';

$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Get parameters
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';

// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);

// Make sure the fileName is unique but only if chunking is disabled
if ($chunks < 2 && file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName)) {
    $ext = strrpos($fileName, '.');
    $fileName_a = substr($fileName, 0, $ext);
    $fileName_b = substr($fileName, $ext);

    $count = 1;
    while (file_exists($targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b))
        $count++;

    $fileName = $fileName_a . '_' . $count . $fileName_b;
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir))
    @mkdir($targetDir);

// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir && is_dir($targetDir) && ($dir = opendir($targetDir))) {
    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge) && ($tmpfilePath != "{$filePath}.part")) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }

    closedir($dir);
} else
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');

// Look for the content type header
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"];

if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]))
    $contentType = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];

// Handle non multipart uploads older WebKit versions didn't support multipart in HTML5
if (strpos($contentType, "multipart") !== false) {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Open temp file
        $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
        if ($out) {
            // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
            $in = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                    fwrite($out, $buff);
            } else
                die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
            fclose($in);
            fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
} else {
    // Open temp file
    $out = fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = fopen("php://input", "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');

        fclose($in);
        fclose($out);
    } else
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
}

// Return JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');

?>
```

Comment: а как вы в `php` проверяли полученные данные и сохраняли в нужную вам директорию, расскажите!?

Comment: там в примере есть файлик upload.php, я добавила его содержимое в вопрос.

Comment: А php какие нибудь ошибки выдаёт? 

У вас включен вывод ошибок?

Comment: Вывод ошибок включен, но ошибку не выдает.

Comment: Всё, разобралась, он просто сохраняет файлы в директорию $targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";, несмотря даже на заданную в настройках другую директорию, потом дальше по коду она почему-то переприсваивается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю защитают мой ответ или нет, раз уж вы сами разобрались, но да, там дей-но сначала берется временная папка с загрузками, а потом в ней еще одна папка создается `uploads`, чтобы меньше с этим мудохаться лучше немного подправить скрипт, а именно

```
// Settings
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
```

изменить на

```
// Settings
$targetDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pluploads";
```

Тогда уж точно в корне сайта появится директория `pluploads`, если ее там не было еще, и загрузятся ваши документы.

А в целом не плохой плагин, надо будет взять его на заметку.